# PHP - Find an object by key in an array of objects, update its value

Tags: php, object

I have an array of objects, and want to update an attribute of one of the objects.

```php
$objs = [ 
    ['value' => 2, 'key' => 'a'], 
    ['value' => 3, 'key' => 'b'] ,
];
```

Let's say I want to set the 'value' of the object with 'key'=>'a' to 5.

Aside from iterating over the array searching for the key, is there any quicker/efficient way of doing this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: There is debate as to why I can't use an associative array. It is because this array is obtained from a JSON value.

If my JSON object is this:

```json
"obj": {
    "a": {
        "key": "a", 
        "value": 2
    }, 
    "b": {
        "key": "b", 
        "value": 3
    }
}
```

There is no guarantee that the order of the objects will be retained, which is required.

Hence I need an index in each object to be able to sort it using `usort()`. So my JSON needs to be:

```json
"obj": {
    "a": {
        "key": "a", 
        "value": 2, 
        "index": 1
    }, 
    "b": {
        "key": "b", 
        "value": 3, 
        "index": 2
    }
}
```

But I cannot use `usort()` on an object, only on arrays. So my JSON needs to be

```json
"obj": [
    {
        "key": "a", 
        "value": 2, 
        "index": 1
    }, {
        "key": "b", 
        "value": 3, 
        "index":2
    }
]
```

Which brings us to the original question.

Comment: Well, for one if the array was formed differently like this -> `['a' => $obj]` you'd only need to check if it's set and set the value:`if(isset($objs['a']))$objs['a']['value'] = $value;`

Comment: I had it as that before, but since this array if formed from JSON, the order of the objects isn't respected. So I had to add an index to each object, and the value and key with that.

Comment: Your json is invalid. Post something that works

Comment: In my opinion, your question has already been solved in many ways; choose any and adapt the logic of your application to your chosen solution.
So change it, for example, add an `order` field to the object. It is not clear what you want from the community)

Comment: @Andreas How is it invalid? Unless you're talking about the missing quotes around 'value' in the first case, which was a typo easily fixed. But your answer helped me so I will accept it as the right approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using `array_column()`, you can pull all the values with the index `key` in the arrays. Then you can find the first occurrence of the value `a` by using `array_search()`. This will only return the first index where it finds a value. Then you can simply replace that value, as you now have the index of that value.

```
$keys = array_column($objs, 'key');
$index = array_search('a', $keys);

if ($index !== false) {
    $objs[$index]['value'] = 5;
}
```

See this [live demo](https://3v4l.org/QUjuY).

- http://php.net/array_search
- http://php.net/array_column

Comment: Mind that array_search returns false if not found which will mess up the array. https://3v4l.org/Lc2Dd p.s. it's the value that OP wants to update not the key.

Comment: You are absolutely correct with regards to `array_search()` returning false. That said, this will update its value, not the key (as you can see in the demo as well).

Comment: It does update the "key", not the value. And as you can see in my demo it updates the wrong item. It should not update any in my example yet it updates "key a"

Comment: Whoops, I got confused with the index names `key`/`value`, and that they are in fact, keys and values. I'll update it. Thanks!

Comment: costing the same as a for loop no?

Comment: It would typically be slightly faster than looping it - but it would depend on the size of the array and how many replacements there is going to be.

Answer (score 2):

I want to recommend you reorginize your array lake that:

```
$objs = [ 
'a' => ['value'=>2, 'key'=>'a'], 
'b' => ['value'=>3, 'key'=>'b'] 
];
```

And now

```
if( array_key_exists( 'a', $objs )) {
  $objs ['a'] ['value'] = 5;
}
```

> I had it like that initially. But I need for the objects to have an
>   index value in them, so I can run usort() on the main array. This is
>   because the array comes from JSON where the original order isn't
>   respected

Then create an `index` array:

```
// When fill `$objs` array
$objs = [];
$arrIndex = [];
$idx = 0;
foreach( $json as $item ) {
  $arrIndex [ $item ['key']] = $idx;
  $objs [$idx ++] = $item;
}

// And your task:

if( array_key_exists( 'a', $arrIndex )) {
  $objs [ $arrIndex ['a']] ['value'] = 5;
}
```

Comment: I had it like that initially. But I need for the objects to have an index value in them, so I can run usort() on the main array. This is because the array comes from JSON where the original order isn't respected.

Comment: @fractal5 I don't understand what you are saying. All arrays have indexes or associative keys. It seems you are trying to get the answer on another question here.

Comment: @Andreas No, he is mean what can't use `key` field as an index of an array.

Comment: But there is no explanation of why. I have not seen any good reason to why he can't use that.

Comment: I change code above. What about that? Of course @Andreas is right: not enough data ))))

Comment: I added some details to my original question, explaining why I can't use an associative array. As for creating an indexed array from the JSON object, what benefit does that offer over just iterating through the original array to find the required object. The only advantage is if I need to do this multiple times, your approach requires one iteration, instead of doing it each time I need to find a key.

Comment: In my opinion, your question has already been solved in many ways; choose any and adapt the logic of your application to your chosen solution. So change it, for example, add an order field to the object. It is not clear what you want from the community)

Comment: @НиколайЛубышев I just gave the extra details to justify why I cannot use your initial approach. The purpose of posting the question is to discuss it and not necessarily find a solution right away, as in this case. Also to help learn. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the array associative with array column. That way you can directly assign the value.

```
$objs = [ ['value'=>2, 'key'=>'a'], ['value'=>3, 'key'=>'b'] ];
$objs = array_column($objs, null, "key");
$objs['a']['value'] = 5;
```

https://3v4l.org/7tJl0

Comment: How is this "more efficient" than looping over the array and updating when you run into an object?

Answer (score 0):

> Aside from iterating over the array searching for the key, is there
>   any quicker/efficient way of doing this?

You have to pay the price of iteration either way.

You can search your collection for the interesting object (takes linear time), or you form some kind of dictionary data structure, e.g. hash table (takes linear time) and then find the interesting object in constant time.

No free lunches here.